# Does CSI secret store provider for Azure require "hostNetwork" set to true?

Tags: azure-aks

I am using CSI secret store driver in AKS to mount secrets in Azure key vault to AKS. I am using helm to deploy the CSI driver in to my AKS.
I ned understand whether CSI secret driver pods needs "hostNetwork" configuration set to true?

If hostNetwork can be set to false, how that can be set when deploying using helm?

Answer (score 0):

Azure CSI secret store driver does need hostNetwork. You can check this in the Helm-Charts:

1. [Azure CSI](https://github.com/Azure/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-azure/blob/master/charts/csi-secrets-store-provider-azure/templates/provider-azure-installer.yaml)
2. [CSI Driver](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/secrets-store-csi-driver/blob/main/charts/secrets-store-csi-driver/templates/secrets-store-csi-driver.yaml)

Comment: According to the helm charts given, hostNetwork is set to true. Is there any helm charts that set hostNetwork to false.

Comment: sry i meant Azure CSI needs it and you should not disable it.

Comment: Is there any reason as to why this should be set to true